# object x has no attribute y . what does it mean?

Tags: python, class

I'm studying python with pyhon crash course. What is wrong with my code?

```
class restaurants():
    def  __init__(self, name, type):
        self.name= name
        self.type = type

def describe(self):
    print(self.name.title() + " is a restaurants that makes this cuisine: " + self.type)

restaurant_one= restaurants( "gianni", "italian")

restaurant_one.describe()
```

AttributeError: 'restaurants' object has no attribute 'describe'

Comment: Since the `def describe` line isn't indented, it's just defining a global function - it's not part of the class, so you can't use it as a method.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there's no `method/property/attribute` named `describe` in the class you defined `Restaurant`

```py
class Restaurant():
    def  __init__(self, name, type):
        self.name= name
        self.type = type

    # all the class methods need to match the class indentation
    def describe(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " is a restaurant that makes this cuisine: " + self.type)

restaurant_one = Restaurant("gianni", "italian")

restaurant_one.describe()
```